Why do we have problem of concept of set?
I am reading George Boolos's "The Iterative Concept of Set," and in the first chapter of this paper, he criticizes Cantor's definition of a set as a whole or totality of objects, pointing out that terms like totality are just as vague as the concept of a set itself. However, he does not address why the vagueness in the definition of a set is problematic. I don't understand why this is an issue. Is it related to Russell's paradox?

Russell paradox is just one of many paradoxes of set theory. I'd say the early ones are more significant, particularly Cantors paradox because they indicate that from the very beginning of 'Cantorism', Cantor knew he was on shaky ground.  Specifically,  Boolos is simply pointing out that Set, Totality, Whole are all loosely circularly defined

The critique is that since defining a Set, by saying it is a totalility, is a nonsense definition. Might as well leave it undefined. The point of defining things is partly for precision and clarity. But, defining Set as Totality doesn't accomplish, and really doesn't accomplish much of anything.

The idea of universal set is quite natural and intuitive. Also the idea of the collection of ALL subsets ( the so-called power set) is plain and intuitive. And then enter mathematics: clearly stated principles (axioms) and rigorously proved facts (theorems): Cantor proved that the power set has "more elements" than the underlying set. Thus , the power set of the universal set must be part of the universal set and must be "greater" than it.

Conclusion: we HAVE problems.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, gracias for the explanation. So P is the power set of the set S. n(P) > n(S) [cardinality of P > cardinality of S]. For the universal set U and its power set E, we have E is an element of U, but n(E) > n(S). How is that a problem? Imagine the set A = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}} and the set B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. We see that n(B) = 5 and n(A) = 2 and still B is an element of A. Please clarify

But A is not the power set of B... If B has 5 elements, its power set has 2^5 elements.

@MauroALLEGRANZA.  So what's special about the power set of a set? I non intelligo

@MauroALLEGRANZA, alright but we're not counting the elements inside the power set, are we??? We should count the power set as 1 set, right?

We will try again... Principle (1): for every set there is its power set. Principle (2): for every set, its power set has more elements wrt the original set. Pinciple (3): there is the "universal" set, i.e. the set that contains every set. Now the universal set contains every set, and thus it must be the greater set; but its power set has more elements. Conclusion: there is a set that is greater than the set containing everything.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, it can't be only about the cardinality of the universal set and the power set of the universal set (as my example above shows). A cardinality-wise bigger set may be contained in a cardinality-wise smaller set.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, "Now the universal set contains every set, and thus it must be the greater set", this may not be true, if you mean numerically greater.

@Hudjefa The problem isn't that the powerset P is an element of the universal set U, the problem is that it's a subset of U. If P is a subset of U then the cardinality of P is at most that of U, but if P is the powerset of U then it provably has strictly larger cardinality, and these two claims contradict each other. FWIW I think this is a red herring, since the proof that P has larger cardinality is literally just Russel's paradox. This is why most set theorists deny the existence of a universal set, and those that don't must deny the Specification principle. You can't have both.

@JadeVanadium, but for A = {{1, 2, 3}, {w}}, and B = {1, 2, 3}, we have B is a subset of A and n(B) = 3 and  n(A) = 2, i.e. n(B) > n(A). A subset may have a higher cardinality than its parent set. Can we assume 1, 2, 3, w are sets.

Can I say that ... the universal set U, since it contains "everything", has n(U) = Max. However for the power set P(U), we have n(P(U)) > n(U), thereby contradicting n(U) = Max???

Human minds are used to comprehending external things including the totality of various things freely and unrestrictedly solely based on their sensed features since they're usually not involved in the construction of the said things from bottom up. Embodied things are always reified, thus the totality of objects or collections of objects therein are naively conceived to be static or non-iterative...

@Hudjefa You are confusing "membership" with "subset". In your example B is a member of A, not a subset of A. I recommend perusing the wikipedia page about "subset" for further clarification.

@JadeVanadium. So n(P(U)) > n(U). This I get (U is the universal set). What does the statement in bold contradict? For any set S, n(U) > n(S) i.e. U, as the universal set, is supposed to be of largest/maximum cardinality?

Have you understood my answer?

A lot of people think that Russell's paradox is the biggest problem, but in fact it is not. Negation is not crucial to the problem of a careless concept of sets.
The problem is with the idea that any collection is itself an object, and that we can define arbitrary collections in terms of collection membership.
The Russell collection is R = { x : x∈set ∧ x∉x }. Here "set" is the collection of all sets, whatever they may be. We can choose to assume that collection membership is well-defined, but we cannot also assume that every collection is an object. After all, there is simply no philosophical basis for that. Thus we cannot assume that R is an object, and there is no paradox.
The problem arises even in the absence of negation and even in intuitionistic logic. Take any objects a,b. Let S = { x : x∈set ∧ ∀t∈{ y : x∈x ∧ y=a } ( t=b ) }. If S∈set, then for any u∈{ y : S∈S ∧ y=a } we have S∈S and u=a, and so ∀t∈{ y : S∈S ∧ y=a } ( t=b ) and a∈{ y : S∈S ∧ y=a }, and hence by ∀elim we get u=a=b. Therefore ∀u∈{ y : S∈S ∧ y=a } ( u=b ), and so S∈S, which then implies by the same reasoning that a=b. Therefore any two objects are equal! What a joke!
The exact same examples show that if we assume that set membership is well-defined, and every collection is an object, then we cannot also assume that collection membership is well-defined. It turns out that we can have such a foundation using 3-valued logic, in which "set" cannot be proven to be a member of "set" and so membership in "set" is not necessarily boolean, which makes both R and S also not provable to be members of "set".

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Cantor was attempting to develop a kind of ontological proof of the existence of sets, as if they are built into the structure of the universe.  In Cantor's defense, it must be said that modern axiomatic approaches to the foundations are a product of the 20th century, whereas at the time of Cantor's writing, there was more of an expectation of a direct link if not an identification of the phenomena and their mathematical description.  Of course there are the various paradoxes, but the problem with "infinite set" is even more basic: it is a fiction that has no referent.
I haven't seen Boolos' book but I assume he is criticizing Cantor not for the purpose of exhuming a cadavre but rather using him as a foil to emphasize the foundational problems that need to be addressed.

As with many of your answers, this could do with some filling out. The Intent of set theory: From Cantor to Axiomatics to American "Modern Math" would be a worthwhile publication for you to write

@Rushi it would be the power set of this answer.

@Rushi, Cantor's metaphysical Platonism has been treated in the literature in some detail. See for example Hill, Claire Ortiz.
Husserl and Cantor. Essays on Husserl's logic and philosophy of mathematics, 169–196,
Synth. Libr., 384, Springer, Dordrecht, 2017.

If we take "Set" := "Totality of Objects" then it would mean, literally, "every object in existence" -- but what objects? The set of Real numbers appears to be a totality, but [0,1] is a valid set and is NOT a totality.
So I agree that "totality of objects" is not a useful definition of set.
That is why the modern version focuses on the abstract properties of "sets" vs trying to describe them explicitly. A set is an object S that has a non-negative number of elements E, such that the following operations are valid (i.e., union, intersection, axiom of choice ("optional")).
Your point about Russel's paradox is also true -- a totality cannot really exist in the sense that if the totality exists then the totality must contain that, ad infinitum.

I don't understand "[0,1] is not a totality". it means that its elements cant be described, so didn't know whole elements of [0, 1]?

@유준상 - a totality of objects means all the objects. This is why Boolos criticizes the vagueness of the definition.

IIUC set theorists don't give much thought as to what is or is not a set. In the ZFC axioms, there is no axiom of the form, "x is a set if and only if P(x)." They make no such formal distinction. IMHO just about any reasonable dictionary definition will do as a starting point to attach some kind of meaning to the axioms.

The critique of Boolos in the introduction of his paper from 1971 seems a bit late, nearly 100 years. Of course one can criticize that Cantor proposes a definition in plain text and uses concepts not better defined than his concept of a set.

Russell’s objection shows that one has to restrict the possibility of
comprehension. Mathematicians have learned the lesson. The concepts
of a set and of an element is now considered an undefined basic
concept and made precise by axioms about their relation. Moreover
set theory distinguishes between classes and sets as proper classes, which restricts set formation.
The step to axiomatization is the same as with Euclid’s elements: “A
point which has no part” is no longer considered a valid definition.
Instead the sentence guides our intuition how to axiomatize the
concept in relation to other undefined basic concepts like line and
plane.


Boolos said that " The idea is paradoxical not in the sense that it is contra- dictory to suppose that some set is a member of itself, for, after all, '(x)(Sx & x=x) is obviously consistent, but that if one understands '∈' as meaning' is a member of, it is very, very peculiar to suppose it" in this paper page 4.(S in here means predicate of "is a set")

I understand the principles behind why the existence of a universal set is problematic, but Boolos seems to be saying here that the concept of a universal set is paradoxical not because it is logically inconsistent, but because it is paradoxical in terms of our conceptual epistemic understanding of sets. Is Boolos ultimately suggesting that this viewpoint is not logically contradictory?

Mathematics, even when formalised, relies on primitive undefined terms. Thus one man's precision may be another man's vagueness.
Secondly, the notion of a set only really becomes problematic when we allow for infinite sets. We could simply do without the axiom of infinity and have a natural theory of finite sets. This ought to be the natural foundation of set theory in the same way that the finite integers are the natural basis for arithmetic.

Some definitions of natural numbers include zero. Would a natural definition of sets include the empty set?
